# Rest API Authentication using Token from mobile application

Tags: php, laravel-5, google-oauth, laravel-socialite

I am building a backend rest api for a android application. It authenticates user and sends the token in `Authorization HEADER`. I am extracting the token from header in a `custom middleware` . Now I tried to check with Socialite whether it provides a way for me to get the user by token. If user does not exist we will create a user else send response as success to android application.

Now in Socialite I cannot implement specific method `getUserByToken($token)` since its protected.

I am not proficient with `laravel`. Can some one guide me?

Thanks, Pavan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Socialite is not an authentication library but a library that provides and interface to Oauth for many social networks.
In order to do what you want you should look at the auth library http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/authentication and I guess that the getUserByToken should go to your User model.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. For the first time android app sends me the  token of the user, if user does not exist in the database i need to contact google with that token and get the user information, store in the database.If user exists just reply with success message back.